# two image button with onClick in same place

Tags: android

I need to do a two image button with onClick.That two image button have to be located in same place.one image button is to start functionality for voice record and other image button is stop functionality for voice record.

I done a functionality exactly.My only problem is to use two image button for stop and start in same place.

I searched many tutorials and SO posts.But I didn't get it.

Anyone can help me with this.

Comment: use toggle button and do custom as you need

Comment: @milapTank No.I have to perform only in image button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use one button and the method setBackgroundResource of the ImageButton. use one and the same button and in the onClick method use this line:

```
yourButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.startImg);  //for start of the recording
```

and

```
yourButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stopImg); //for stop of the recording
```

Comment: setImageResource is better than setBackgroundResource.Thank you for your answer.please check my answer :)

Comment: Okay, yes, I agree with you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (myAudioRecorder==null) {
        myAudioRecorder.start();
        audioButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
    } else if (myAudioRecorder != null) {
        audioButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.record);
    }
```